# Format table cells according to datatype using Jinja2/Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jinja2

I'm trying to automate a manual task where, every day, a colleague logs in to various systems, cuts/pastes chunks of data into an email, and then sends it to a group of people. I'm using Jinja2 for the template engine, and Bootstrap to make it look beautiful. Here's what's been done so far: https://gist.github.com/alexwoolford/ac342289bb90c5dda524

Some of the columns are percentages, some are counts, and some are dollars. For percentages, I'd like to multiply the value by 100, round to two decimal places, and add a percent sign (e.g. 0.34567 would be displayed as 34.57%). For counts, I'd like to comma separate the thousands (e.g. 1234567 would be displayed as 1,234,567). For dollars, I'd like to add a dollar sign, round to the nearest whole integer, and comma separate the thousands (e.g. 2345.67 would be displayed as $2,346).

Ideally, I'd like to simply add a class to the table cells in the template like this:

```
<td class='percent'>{{ row.some_percent_val }}</td>
<td class='count'>{{ row.some_count }}</td>
<td class='dollar'>{{ row.some_dollar_value }}</td>
```

What would I need to do to the Jinja2 template to format the columns correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

css is not going to give you what you want. You'll need to use the jinja filter system.  Some of the built filters like format can probably get you most of the way there.  But you may need to create some custom ones.  For example you could do this to get a nice dollar display:

```
<td class='dollar'>{{ "${:,.2f}" | format (row.some_dollar_value)}}</td>
```

if you prefer,  you can use all the built in python methods on the string variable:

```
{{ "${:,.2f}".format (row.some_dollar_value)}}
```

Documentation for creating your own custom filters can be found here:

http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/api/#custom-filters

Comment: That's simple and beautiful. Thanks so much, @RobertMoskal.